# count the number of elements in an XSL for-each loop?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have been trying for the past day to figure out how to count the number of elements in an XSL for-each loop.  I have tried doing it with javascript but can't seem to get it to work.  I'm not sure if it's just a matter of not displaying the output correctly or if you can even do this with XSLT.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is a nasty bug that I was not prepared for.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var colATotal=0;

function loopCounterA(){
  colATotal++;
}

function printA(){
   document.write(colATotal);
}
</script>

<xsl:for-each select='bookmarks/category'>
<xsl:for-each select='./bookmark'>

<script type="text/javascript">
loopCounterA(); 
printA();
</script>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**From comments:**

> I figured showing all the code may be
>   a waste of time. I have a div columnA
>   and a div columnB, both of which are
>   vertical columns. My boss wants all of
>   the bookmarks to wrap, but i can't
>   start the wrap in the middle of a
>   category block. My intention is to
>   keep track of 3 variables to do this:
>   total bookmarks in columnA so far (A),
>   total bookmarks in columnB so far (B),
>   and the number of bookmarks in the
>   next category block to be placed (C).
>   if B + C is greater than A, I will
>   place the block into columnA and I'll
>   place it into columnB otherwise. Does
>   this make more sense now? Thx so much.

Comment: Do you simply need the number of category elements multiplied by the number of category elements? There are better ways to achieve that (the `count` function comes to mind).

Comment: no, i am placing category blocks in two columns, and in order to place them as evenly as possible, i want to keep track of the number of bookmarks already placed in both columns and compare that number with the number of bookmarks in the next block to be placed, if you know what i mean....

Comment: I would try [position() mod 2 == 0] wither as predicate or as a test condition to split the list into two buckets and make even "rows" go into one column and "odd" rows into another. If you need a different type of split I would still focus on how a simple math around count() and position() can tell you how. In the code that you show it's not clear what you intend to do - generate JS with your XSLT or actually run the JS inside the XSLT. The latter just doesn't work by design. Show a piece of the original XML tree and a longer code fragment and you'll likely get a solution :)

Comment: Check my answer for a XSLT only solution.

Answer (score 3):

This stylesheet (your algorithm):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="bookmarks">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="category[1]"/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="category">
        <xsl:param name="pColumnA" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="pColumnB" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:variable name="vTest" select="count($pColumnB/bookmark|bookmark)
                                           > count($pColumnA/bookmark)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vColumnA" select="$pColumnA|self::*[$vTest]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vColumnB" select="$pColumnB|self::*[not($vTest)]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vNext" select="following-sibling::category[1]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vNext">
            <xsl:with-param name="pColumnA" select="$vColumnA"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pColumnB" select="$vColumnB"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:if test="not($vNext)">
            <div id="ColumnA">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$vColumnA"/>
            </div>
            <div id="ColumnB">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$vColumnB"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<bookmarks>
    <category id="a">
        <bookmark id="1"/>
        <bookmark id="2"/>
        <bookmark id="3"/>
    </category>
    <category id="b">
        <bookmark id="4"/>
        <bookmark id="5"/>
    </category>
    <category id="c">
        <bookmark id="6"/>
        <bookmark id="7"/>
        <bookmark id="8"/>
        <bookmark id="9"/>
        <bookmark id="10"/>
    </category>
    <category id="d">
        <bookmark id="11"/>
        <bookmark id="12"/>
        <bookmark id="13"/>
        <bookmark id="14"/>
        <bookmark id="15"/>
    </category>
</bookmarks>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <div id="ColumnA">
        <category id="a">
            <bookmark id="1"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="2"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="3"></bookmark>
        </category>
        <category id="c">
            <bookmark id="6"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="7"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="8"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="9"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="10"></bookmark>
        </category>
    </div>
    <div id="ColumnB">
        <category id="b">
            <bookmark id="4"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="5"></bookmark>
        </category>
        <category id="d">
            <bookmark id="11"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="12"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="13"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="14"></bookmark>
            <bookmark id="15"></bookmark>
        </category>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `count()` XPath function on the predicate in the `select` attribute.

Comment: thanks that is very helpful.  any advice on what to do about keeping track of them through javascript? i want to place each category block into one of two columns and i want to keep track of the total bookmarks in each column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count()` function and use it to simplify your JavaScript. No need to iterate over the XML to generate JavaScript that gets invoked n number of times to produce a count.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var colATotal=<xsl:value-of select='count(bookmarks/category/bookmark)'>;

function printA(){
   document.write(colATotal);
}

printA();

</script>
```

If the goal of putting it into the JavaScript is just to turn it into HTML that has the count and you were just using JavaScript in order to create the HTML that you want(and couldn't figure out how to do in XSLT), ***try asking how to do it in XSLT***.

It isn't as hard as you might imagine, it's just done differently than you may be used to. XSLT is a declarative programming style and you are approaching it as a procedural programmer.

You could just select the count of the elements and put it directly into your HTML output e.g.:

```
<b>The total count of bookmarks is:</b> <xsl:value-of select='count(bookmarks/category/bookmark)'>
```

Comment: thanks that is very helpful.  any advice on what to do about keeping track of them through javascript? i want to place each category block into one of two columns and i want to keep track of the total bookmarks in each column

Comment: What is the criteria for your columns? You can adjust the count to filter and only count bookmarks that belong to a particular category. It's helpful to see more of your source file and example output in order to suggest a solution. `xsl:number` might also be useful for you to produce the types of counts based upon current position. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_number.asp

Comment: i figured showing all the code may be a waste of time.  i have a div columnA and a div columnB, both of which are vertical columns.  my boss wants all of the bookmarks to wrap, but i can't start the wrap in the middle of a category block.  my intention is to keep track of 3 variables to do this: total bookmarks in columnA so far (A), total bookmarks in columnB so far (B), and the number of bookmarks in the next category block to be placed (C).  if B + C is greater than A, i will place the block into columnA and i'll place it into columnB otherwise.  does this make more sense now?  thx so much